# Problem with build an example “NetBeans Platform Quick Start Using Maven”

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I tried to perform muti-module example for integration maven and netbeans 
(https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-quickstart.html) step by step. 
But soon after finishing the step called "Adding a Window Component to the Module" when first try out the application with Build with Dependencies.I got the message:

> Failed to execute goal on project MavenPlatformWordApp:      
>  
> Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:MavenPlatformWordApp:nbm:1.0-SNAPSHOT:    
>  
> Could not find artifact com.mycompany:MavenWordEngine:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT

I dont know why Netbeans IDE11.2 could not find this file though it is displayed at the target position on the tree components and is placed in D:\JAVA\NetBeansProjects\MavenWordEngine\target\MavenWordEngine-1.0-SNAPHOT.jar     
 
So I decided extra to add dependent <module> **MavenWordEngine** </module>  to the <modules> section of **pom.xml [MavenPlatformWordApp-parent]**
>

> ```
>  <modules> <br />
>    <module>branding</module>
>    <module>application</module>
>    <module>MavenWordEngine</module>
>  </modules>
> ```

This is a lie - because this child module MavenWordEngine really exists !!!
The brief projects layout looks like this:

```
MavenPlatformWordApp-app
|       |-->  pom.xml
|
|-->  MavenPlatformWordApp-branding
|       |-->  pom.xml
|
|-->  MavenPlatformWordApp-parent
|       |-->  pom.xml
|
|--> MavenWordEngine
      |-->  pom.xml
```

---

Here is       **pom.xml [MavenPlatformWordApp-parent]**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"> 
        <modelVersion> 4.0.0 </modelVersion> 

        <groupId> com.mycompany </groupId> 
        <artifactId> MavenPlatformWordApp-parent </artifactId> 
        <version> 1.0-SNAPSHOT </version> 
        <packaging> pom </packaging> 

        <name> MavenPlatformWordApp-parent </name> 

        <repositories> 
            <repository> 
                <id> netbeans </id> 
                <name> NetBeans </name> 
                <url> http://bits.netbeans.org/nexus/content/groups/netbeans/ </url> 
            </repository> 
        </repositories> 

        <build> 
            <pluginManagement> 
                <plugins> 
                    <plugin> 
                        <groupId> org.apache.netbeans.utilities </groupId> 
                        <artifactId> nbm-maven-plugin </artifactId> 
                        <version> 4.3 </version> 
                        <extensions> true </extensions> 
                        <configuration> 
                            <brandingToken> ${brandingToken} </brandingToken> 
                            <cluster> ${brandingToken} </cluster> 
                     </configuration> 
                    </plugin> 
                    <plugin> 
                        <groupId> org.apache.maven.plugins </groupId> 
                        <artifactId> maven-compiler-plugin </artifactId> 
                        <version> 3.8.1 </version> 
                        <configuration> 
                            <source> 1.8 </source> 
                            <target> 1.8 </target> 
                     </configuration> 
                 </plugin> 
                 <plugin> 
                    <groupId> org.apache.maven.plugins </groupId> 
                    <artifactId> maven-jar-plugin </artifactId> 
                    <version> 3.1.2 </version> 
             </plugin> 
             </plugins> 
         </pluginManagement> 
     </build> 

        <modules> 
            <module> branding </module> 
            <module> application </module> 
            <module> MavenWordEngine </module> 
        </modules> 

        <properties> 
            <netbeans.version> RELEASE110 </netbeans.version> 
            <brandingToken> mavenplatformwordapp </brandingToken> 
        </properties> 
 </project>
```

---

And here is       **pom.xml [MavenPlatformWordApp-app]**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"> 
        <modelVersion> 4.0.0 </modelVersion> 
        <parent> 
            <groupId> com.mycompany </groupId> 
            <artifactId> MavenPlatformWordApp-parent </artifactId> 
            <version> 1.0-SNAPSHOT </version> 
        </parent> 

        <artifactId> MavenPlatformWordApp-app </artifactId> 
        <packaging> nbm-application </packaging> 

        <name> MavenPlatformWordApp-app </name> 

        <properties> 
            <project.build.sourceEncoding> UTF-8 </project.build.sourceEncoding> 
            <all.clusters> ${project.build.directory}/${brandingToken} </all.clusters> 
        </properties> 

        <dependencies> 
            <dependency> 
                <groupId> org.netbeans.cluster </groupId> 
                <artifactId> platform </artifactId> 
                <version> ${netbeans.version} </version> 
                <type> pom </type> 
            </dependency> 
            <dependency> 
                <groupId> ${project.groupId} </groupId> 
                <artifactId> MavenPlatformWordApp-branding </artifactId> 
                <version> ${project.version} </version> 
            </dependency> 
            <dependency> 
                <groupId> org.netbeans.api </groupId> 
                <artifactId> org-netbeans-modules-nbjunit </artifactId> 
                <version> ${netbeans.version} </version> 
                <scope> test </scope>  
            </dependency> 
            <dependency> 
                <groupId> ${project.groupId} </groupId> 
                <artifactId> MavenWordEngine </artifactId> 
                <version> ${project.version} </version> 
         </dependency> 
     </dependencies> 

        <build> 
            <plugins> 
                <plugin> 
                    <groupId> org.apache.netbeans.utilities </groupId> 
                    <artifactId> nbm-maven-plugin </artifactId> 
                </plugin>          
                <plugin> 
                    <groupId> org.apache.maven.plugins </groupId> 
                    <artifactId> maven-surefire-plugin </artifactId> 
                    <version> 2.12.2 </version> 
                    <configuration> 
                        <systemPropertyVariables> 
                            <all.clusters> ${all.clusters} </all.clusters> 
                            <branding.token> ${brandingToken} </branding.token> 
                        </systemPropertyVariables> 
                    </configuration> 
                </plugin> 
            </plugins> 
     </build> 

        <profiles> 
            <profile> 
                <id> deployment </id> 
                <build> 
                    <plugins> 
                        <plugin> 
                            <groupId> org.apache.netbeans.utilities </groupId> 
                            <artifactId> nbm-maven-plugin </artifactId> 
                            <executions> 
                                <execution> 
                                    <id> extra </id> 
                                    <goals> 
                                        <goal> autoupdate </goal> 
                                        <goal> webstart-app </goal> 
                                        <goal> build-installers </goal> 
                                 </goals> 
                             </execution> 
                         </executions> 
                     </plugin> 
                 </plugins> 
             </build> 
         </profile> 
     </profiles> 
 </project>
```

---

And here is dependant   **pom.xml [MavenWordEngine]**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"> 
        <parent>  
            <artifactId>  MavenPlatformWordApp-parent  </artifactId>  
            <groupId>  com.mycompany  </groupId>  
            <version>  1.0-SNAPSHOT  </version>  
        </parent> 
        <modelVersion> 4.0.0 </modelVersion> 
        <groupId> com.mycompany </groupId> 
        <artifactId> MavenWordEngine </artifactId> 
        <version> 1.0-SNAPSHOT </version> 
        <packaging> nbm </packaging> 
        <build> 
            <plugins> 
                <plugin> 
                    <groupId> org.apache.netbeans.utilities </groupId> 
                    <artifactId> nbm-maven-plugin </artifactId> 
                    <version> 4.3 </version> 
                    <extensions> true </extensions> 
                </plugin> 
                <plugin> 
                    <groupId> org.apache.maven.plugins </groupId> 
                    <artifactId> maven-compiler-plugin </artifactId> 
                    <version> 3.8.1 </version> 
                    <configuration> 
                        <source> 1.8 </source> 
                        <target> 1.8 </target> 
                 </configuration> 
                </plugin> 
                <plugin> 
                    <groupId> org.apache.maven.plugins </groupId> 
                    <artifactId> maven-jar-plugin </artifactId> 
                    <version> 3.1.2 </version> 
                    <configuration> 
                        <archive> 
                            <manifestFile> ${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF </manifestFile> 
                        </archive> 
                 </configuration> 
             </plugin> 
         </plugins> 
     </build> 
        <dependencies> 
            <dependency> 
                <groupId> org.netbeans.api </groupId> 
                <artifactId> org-netbeans-api-annotations-common </artifactId> 
                <version> RELEASE110 </version> 
            </dependency> 
            <dependency> 
                <groupId> org.netbeans.api </groupId> 
                <artifactId> org-openide-windows </artifactId> 
                <version> RELEASE110 </version> 
            </dependency> 
            <dependency> 
                <groupId> org.netbeans.api </groupId> 
                <artifactId> org-openide-util </artifactId> 
                <version> RELEASE110 </version> 
            </dependency> 
            <dependency> 
                <groupId> org.netbeans.api </groupId> 
                <artifactId> org-openide-util-ui </artifactId> 
                <version> RELEASE110 </version> 
            </dependency> 
            <dependency> 
                <groupId> org.netbeans.api </groupId> 
                <artifactId> org-openide-util-lookup </artifactId> 
                <version> RELEASE110 </version> 
         </dependency> 
            <dependency> 
                <groupId> org.netbeans.api </groupId> 
                <artifactId> org-openide-awt </artifactId> 
                <version> RELEASE110 </version> 
            </dependency> 
            <dependency> 
                <groupId> org.netbeans.api </groupId> 
                <artifactId> org-netbeans-modules-settings </artifactId> 
                <version> RELEASE110 </version> 
         </dependency> 
     </dependencies> 
        <properties> 
            <project.build.sourceEncoding> UTF-8 </project.build.sourceEncoding> 
     </properties> 
 </project>
```

Does anybody know what is the reason, I think that the good NetBeans's pattern should work well.